# Serialize a derived class without access to base class

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, serialization

I need to serialize a derived class in my Windows Phone 7 Project for tombstoning state.
But I don't have access to the code to the base class - exposed by a Library -.

```
//don't have access to this class
public class A
{
     public string member1 {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class B : A
{
     public B(){}; //CTOR

     [DataMember]
     public string member2 {get;set;}
}
```

When the system try to serialize (I save it to PhoneApplicationPage.State => so it's auto serializing) : it's not working, the exception (InvalidDataContractException) says **"Type 'B' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.  Consider marking the base type 'A' with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type."**

Should I implement a custom serializer ? How can I do that (in Windows Phone 7)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than derive from the library class, you could have a member variable that of that type and expose the properties of the library class member via custom getters and setters:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    BaseClass Wrapped { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Wrapped = new BaseClass( );
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string member1
    {
        get { return Wrapped.member1; }
        set { Wrapped.member1= value; }
    }
}
```